# Why won't `setTimeout` work right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click a button that will fire a function 5 seconds after click UNLESS it is clicked again, in which case the counter restarts.

```
var timeoutId;

function dummyFunction(this){
  console.log(this);
  console.log('FIRING');
}

$(function(){
        $('#some-button').click(function(){
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            timeoutId = setTimeout( 
                dummyFunction(this), 
                5000
            );
        });
});
```

But when I click `#some-button`, `dummyFunction()` fires immediately instead of after five seconds.

Why does it do this? Is it a jQuery thing? If so, what's the workaround?

Comment: `var self = this, timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){dummyFunction(self)}, 5000);`

Comment: You also can't have an argument or variable called `this`, like you're passing to: `dummyFunction(this)`. I'm guessing this is a demo fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running your function instead of passing it as a parameter.

Try this:

```
timeoutId = setTimeout( 
    dummyFunction.bind(this), 
    5000
);
```

Note: if you want to pass `this` as an actual parameter then use: `dummyFunction.bind(this, this)`

Comment: What is the difference between `dummyFunction.bind(this)` and `dummyFunction.bind(this, this)`?

Comment: @Username - `Function.prototype.bind()` passes the `thisArg` (context) as the first parameter, then each parameter after that is passed as an argument to the function. I've described this a bit more in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To match exactly what you're demonstrating in your question code, do this:

```
var self = this;

setTimeout(function(){
    dummyFunction.apply(null, self);
}, 5000);
```

The anonymous function (`function(){}`) creates a new scope separate but within the scope from where `self` is declared, then when `dummyFunction()` is called, `self` is passed as the first argument.

Note that `null` represents the `this` argument for the context in the function you're setting it to; when you pass `null` to `Function.prototype.apply()` as the first argument, you get `window` for `this`.

Here's an example of the three methods for calling a function and setting it's context:

```
function dummyFunction(self){
    console.log(self, this);
}

function abc(){
    var self = this;

    this.bind = function(){
        setTimeout(dummyFunction.bind(this, this), 1000);
    }
    this.apply = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            dummyFunction.apply(null, self);
        }, 2000);
    }
    this.call = function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            dummyFunction.call(null, self);
        }, 3000);
    }
}

var a = new abc();

console.log('bind'), a.bind();
console.log('apply'), a.apply();
console.log('call'), a.call();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qwb5fxr7/3

I created an object (`abc`) to get a custom context. Which one of these you use/need depends on how you want to use `this` in the function you're calling:

- Use `.call()` or `.apply()` if you want to pass `this` as an argument, the only difference is how the arguments are passed. To do this, you must not use `this` as the argument name in the function definition. In addition, `.call()` and `.apply()` actually *call* the function, so you have to wrap it in an anonymous function and pass `this` as a variable that you've stored in the parent scope.
- However, what you want here is `.bind()`, since it creates a *new* function and passes that back with the context attached. This means you don't lose `this` when it's actually called later (basically, `.bind()` returns something that can be invoked, whereas `.apply()` and `.call()` immediately invoke the function). EvilZebra's answer shows how to do this (plus the `abc.bind()` function in my answer). See the [`setTimeout()` examples in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout).

---

Documentation:

- [`this` and context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
- [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)